# Shadowbox to open a page

Tags: jsp, servlets, lightbox, shadowbox

I am starting a JSP page from my servlet. I want to know if I can put any code inside the JSP page so that the page would open in a shadowbox instead of a new tab

Comment: I should have mentioned. http://www.shadowbox-js.com/
.Its something like what Facebook uses to display images

Comment: what you will try...if you should like as,http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html